# Read cookies cross sub-domain in WebApi

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, cookies, cross-domain, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core 3.1 WebAPI application where UI and API hosted on different subdomains of the same root domain, say `https://api.domain.com` and `https://ui.domain.com`

UI site sets some cookies (.domain.com) that I need to read in the API backend, but no matter what I try - cookies are never passed in. I have CORS policy enabled that allows wildcard subdomains and credentials in my `Startup.cs` ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("https://*.domain.com")
                           .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains
                           .AllowAnyMethod()
                           .AllowAnyHeader()
                           .AllowCredentials();
                });
            });
```

And use it in app Configure:

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

I also set Cookie policy:

```
    app.UseCookiePolicy(
        new CookiePolicyOptions()
        {
            MinimumSameSitePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Lax

        });
```

But when calling `https://api.domain.com` from `https://ui.domain.com` expected cookies aren't there.

If both UI and API are on the same exact subdomain - it works. What am I missing?

Comment: if you are calling it by ajax check to set "crossDomain: true
xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }"

Comment: @user1519979 The client is in Angular, which I am not very familiar with, and it's not my code. I've set `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true` but it seems to have no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding `{ withCredentials: true }` to every `$http` request. A bit of a pain, but this is the only thing that worked for me.